# Cannot seem to change IIS log settings

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

- IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2

I have discovered that IIS is no longer logging. So to try and isolate the issue I wanted to change some of the logging settings. However both at host and site level the logging settings seem to be permanently disabled (as per the attached screenshot). So do I need to stop both the web servers on there before I can change this? I tried stopping the non-important mobile site but the controls on the page remain disabled.

Any ideas on how I get to set the logging settings without restarting the web service and/or the machine?

[image]

Comment: If you look to the right of that screen in the `Actions` pane, do you see an `Enable` link?

Comment: Talk about a doh!!! moment.... Had to click enable. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common reason for why you see grayed out elements on the `Logging` dialog is because the feature is not enabled.

In the `Actions` pane on the right side of IIS Manager click on `Enable`.

Logging is enabled by default, so you only run into this if someone disabled it before.